# Using a Gandi domain and a cloudfront default cert, how can I set up my CNAME records so that https works?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, web-hosting, amazon-s3

I have a website (www.foo.com), registered with Gandi. I have a static page on Amazon S3 (let's say s3.foo.us-west.com). I also have a Cloudfront distribution (foo.cloudfront.net).

Originally, my Gandi domain had a CNAME pointed at my amazon S3 bucket (www.foo.com -> s3.foo-us-west.com). When I loaded this page, it worked, but it was http-only. I also had my cloudfront distribution pointed at that page, and when I loaded the cloudfront url (foo.cloudfront.net), I'd get https (because i set it to redirect to https) using the default cloudfront cert. The problem here is that since there was no CNAME, the url bar didn't reflect my domain.

I went ahead and pointed my Gandi domain (using CNAME) to my cloudfront distribution (foo.cloudfront.net), and added a CNAME to my cloudfront distribution to my domain (www.foo.com). This "worked" in that loading www.foo.com upgraded to https, kept the URL bar the same, and loaded my website, but Chrome tells me that the certificate can't be verified and it may not be secure.

How can I set this up so that the default cloudfront cert is used when accessing www.foo.com (as it was used when accessing the cloudfront url in the first setup)? Or must I use an external cert?

Answer (score 2):

A large point of HTTPS is to make sure that the server you're talking to has a certificate for the name you used to reach it (that is, the name visible in the browser's URL bar). So no, you can't use a default certificate and your own name. If you could, that'd be a security problem. You need to get a certificate that has your domain name in it.

Comment: +1 and Part 2: No, an "external" cert is not needed.  See [Amazon Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) for free CloudFront certs for domains you own or control.